# If I scale my google cloud sql instance up, can I use the same database which exists on cloud sql instance previously

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

I have a question for google cloud sql. I used the mySQL instance of google cloud sql, this instance type is f1-micro.

If my service grows up, I should need more performance. 
In this case, can I use the same database which exists on previous cloud sql instance, if I scale my sql instance up? 
I'm just wondering if I can continue to use the same database(containing original data) just by shutting down the instance and rebooting to the new server specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, changing the size of the instance does not affect the data though you will see a brief downtime while the instance is resized.